# Wrong answer explanation - How many binary words of length n with at least m 0's

Tags: combinatorics

I understand the answer would be the number of all combinations minus (nc0)-(nc1)...-(nc(m-1)), correct me if I'm wrong.
Still I cant understand why would this be a wrong answer:
 $$ 2^{n-m}{n \choose m}$$

Would love if someone can explain
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm guessing your reasoning behind that answer is this: Since the string should contain at least $m$ zeroes, we first place $m$ zeroes in $m$ of the $n$ places, and this can be done in $\binom n m$ ways. And now the remaining $n - m$ places can be filled in any way whatsoever (zeroes or ones), which is possible in $2^{n - m}$ ways.

That is overcounting. For example, let $n = 3$, and $m = 1$. Then $\binom n m$ counts these three partial strings:
$$0--,\ -0-,\ --0 $$

And the remaining places can be filled in $2^{n-m} = 4$ ways as follows
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{Bits inserted} & 0-- & {}-0-{} & --0\\
\hline
0,0 & 000 & 000 & 000\\
0,1 & 001 & 001 & 010\\
1,0 & 010 & 100 & 100\\
1,1 & 011 & 101 & 110
\end{array}

It is clear that overcounting occurs. But why? Because while inserting zeroes in $\binom n m$ ways, you may place a zero in the $i$<sup>th</sup> location and leave the $j$<sup>th</sup> location empty, in some of these cases; then when filling the remaining places with zeroes and ones in $2^{n - m}$ ways, the $j$<sup>th</sup> location also may be filled with a zero, in some of the cases. But in some other of the $\binom n m$ cases, you may fill the $j$<sup>th</sup> location with a zero and leave the $i$<sup>th</sup> one empty; and then fill this $i$<sup>th</sup> vacant place with a zero when filling all the vacant places. So the same case gets counted at least twice [actually many more times, as you can see from the example].

---

The correct answer is the one that you have mentioned in the question, that is $$2^n - \binom n 0 - \binom n 1 - \cdots - \binom n {m - 1} = 2^n - \sum_{i = 0}^{m - 1} \binom n i.$$ Of course, it's simpler to write $$\binom n m + \binom n {m + 1} + \cdots + \binom n n = \sum_{i = m}^n \binom n i$$
instead. Here, each $\binom n i$ counts the number of binary strings with exactly $i$ zeroes, by counting the number of ways $i$ zeroes can be placed in $i$ of the $n$ places (which is also what we do in the first part of the wrong method described earlier). However now, there is no overcounting since after we place the $i$ zeroes, there is only one way to fill the rest of the $n - i$ places with ones, and for any other $j \ne i$ number of zeroes, we get a different string (because they differ in the total number of zeroes they contain), making these mutually exclusive cases. As $i$ runs from $m$ to $n$, we get all possible number of zeroes greater than or equal to $m$ (thus fulfilling the "at least $m$ zeroes" condition). The first formula works in much the same way, except that it excludes all the invalid cases (less than $m$ zeroes) from the total $2^n$ cases. Apart from this combinatorial reason, you can also observe that these two are equal because $$\sum_{i = 0}^{m-1} \binom n i + \sum_{i = m}^n \binom n i = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom n i = 2^n.$$

Comment: And what about $$\sum_{i=m}^n {n \choose m}$$?

Comment: @Evi I've updated the answer with an explanation of that

Answer (score 0):

I assume the answer is obtained by placing zeros into specified $m$ positions and counting all binary combinations possible for the rest $n-m$ positions, and then changing the specified $m$ positions in all possible $\binom nm$ ways.

This reasoning is however wrong because it overcounts, since any particular sequence which has more than $m$ zeros will be counted several times. It can be especially drastically seen on the example of $(0,0,\dots,0)$ sequence, which will be counted $\binom nm$ times instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try your formula on a case where it's easy to see what's going on: Length 2 binary strings with at least one $0$. There are three of them. Your formula says four. What's going on?

Your formula comes from thinking like this: Choose $m$ bits to be 0, then pick the rest arbitrarily. So we get

- Pick the first bit to be 1. There are now $2^1$ possibilities: $00$ and $01$.
- Pick the second bit too be 1. There are now $2^1$ possibilities: $00$ and $10$.
- In total that makes 4 possibilities

Do you see the problem?